# Why some docstrings of methods in class are not shown in pydoc?

Tags: python, docstring, pydoc

I am using `pydoc` to create documentation. 
But it is only displaying the `docstring` for a class and for methods such as `__init__`. Is there any parameter to be passed to `pydoc` to create a documentation for **each method** of a class as well?

Example:

```
class myclass(some_other_class):
    """
    This is 'class' docstring.
    """

    def __init__(self):
       """
       This is docsctring for __init__ method.
       """
       pass

    def mymethod(self, some_parameter):
       """
       This is docstring for mymethod function.
       """
       pass
```

Now when I use pydoc on this code, I do not see "This is docstring for mymethod function." in the output generated.

Comment: Example code please?

Comment: Instance methods, class methods, static methods? Leading-underscore method names? Any decorators involved?

Comment: Yes. There are instance methods, class methods, leading_underscore methods, and decorators as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks perfectly fine, I put it in a **script.py** file, removed the "some_other_class" reference, and ran `python -m pydoc -w script`. It generated the following HTML:

> ```
> class myclass
>       This is 'class' docstring.
>
>       Methods defined here:
>           __init__(self)
>             This is docsctring for __init__ method.
>           mymethod(self, some_parameter)
>             This is docstring for mymethod function.
> ```